# always and normally

Tags: tense, past-tense

I'm confused about what tenses I should use after *always* and *normally*.

*You always **leaves** the milk outside*

or

*You always **left** the milk outside*

(I was annoyed so I told him not to do it)

*I usually **buy** this brand of biscuit*

or

I usually  **bought** this brand of biscuit

Comment: Use the present tense if the action is still happening (I usually buy), and the past if it is no longer happening (I usually bought this brand of biscuit when I lived in the USA, but I can't get them in the UK.)

Answer (score 1):

After you fix the grammar issue (you leave **not** you leaves), pretend "always" isn't there.

You're dealing with the noun before it.

These are correct phrases:

- You leave
- He/She leaves
- They leave
- You left
- They left
- He/She left

You can then put "always" before the verb:

- You always leave
- He/She always leaves
- They always leave
- You always left
- They always left
- He/She always left

Same goes for "usually" or "normally".

Comment: You didn't notice 'you always leaves'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey You're right. I updated my answer.